How can i level a porch which slopes in 2 directions
I have a porch that is at the corner of a cabin. Naturally, the porch slopes away from the house, in two directions. I would like to enclose the porch, and use it as a dining area.
It’s a fairly dramatic slope, perhaps 3 inches over 8 feet. If it were in just one direction I think I could handle this, but I can’t wrap my head around how to handle the two slopes.
The floor is plywood.
The cabin is quite old and rustic and the foundation is just cement blocks, so I don’t feel comfortable adding a lot of weight to the structure.
I can also “live with it” and I’m already considering just leveling a table to accommodate the slopes!
But I would love to hear some suggestions.

Is your porch made of wood?

You'll want to cut "sleeper" joists to overlay the existing joists (and the existing subfloor, if you prefer). Then you can install new subfloor (or finish floor, if you were to just varnish the plywood).

Establish the height of your new floor. This may be the high point of the current floor, or it may be a compromise below that. You decide what makes sense with the adjacent floors.

Run a grid of carpenter's line. (You could also use a laser level if you happen to have access to one.) You'd do this by leveling to the corners of the room from the height established in step 1. Use large nails or screws so they're stout. Once you have heights at all four corners, run a line around the room. Make it nice and snug so any sag is negligible.

Over the first joist, pull another line between the perimeter lines. This could be set up so you can slide it along to each joist.

From one side of the room, measure and mark at intervals of say 24" from the low point along the joist line. At each mark, measure from the floor to the string. Write it on the floor at that location (or make a map on paper).

Once you have the thickness at each point, transfer the dimensions to appropriately sized two-by lumber on the same intervals from the end. Drop any numbers less than say 1/8", as they won't be worth trying to cut. Use a straightedge to connect them and create a continuous line.

Cut the sleepers. A circular saw is fine. You can easily curve to match your line, which may be a bit zig-zaggy.

Set all sleepers in place and temporarily set them with screws into the old floor.

Examine the new framing for flatness. Make any adjustments to your satisfaction.

Use heavy-duty construction adhesive and screws long enough to reach the original joists to permanently set the new joists.

Install your new subfloor, again using construction adhesive and screws or ring-shank nails.



Maybe you can lift the joists but the plywood at the corner is not going to like that. as that will stretch it
Othwerwise you're cutting 2x4s into big wedges to install on top of the joists.  and the plywood has come off for that anyway.
